# Is it possible to combine two jquery functions for the same CSS selector?

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a css selector in which it is toggling the default class display:none and show class display:block.

Is it possible to merge the below in a single query?

```
$('.abc .def').slideToggle();

$('.abc .def').toggleClass('show');
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to have a custom class just for toggling display because the `slideToggle` function is already modifying the display property inline.

If you still want to toggle the class as well, probably the best place is in the callback function, like this:

```
$('.abc .def').slideToggle(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('show');
})
```

This will toggle the class once the slide animation is done.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the 2 functions after each other, they always return the current object for [chaining](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp)

```
$('.abc .def').slideToggle().toggleClass('show');
```